# Dart Editor Unable to run current selection - please select a runnable resource

Tags: dart, dart-editor

Last year I thought I would give Dart a try, so I downloaded the Dart + Editor zip from the dartlang.org website and got it working on my Ubuntu 12.04 environment. When trying to get the Sunflower demo to run (by clicking the Run button), I got the "Unable to run current selection - please select a runnable resource" error. After exploring Google for answers, I found nothing, so I gave up on Dart at the time, not wanting to spend the time on something that is still buggy. Since then I prepared a completely new Ubuntu 14.04 environment on a new computer and thought I would give Dart another try. So I downloaded and installed it again this year and I am experiencing the exact same problem, still with no answers from Google searches. If this were a bug, I figured something like this would have been resolved after a year, or at least some discussion somewhere on Google about it. Am I doing something consistently wrong?

1. I extracted the dart zip into /opt/dart
2. I installed openjdk-7-jre
3. I executed DartEditor and it runs
4. I select the Sunflower demo
5. I click the green Run button
6. I get the following error: "Unable to run current selection - please select a runnable resource"

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the context menu on the entry page file (index.html or sunflower.html) in the web sub-directory and choose `Run in Dartium`

There is no unique or default entry point in a Dart package and no way to configure one.
You always have to run a specific Dart script file or HTML page that contains a ` tag.

I almost never used the run Button in the toolbar.
When you have for example the menu `Run/Always run last launch` activated and run an entry point like described above the toolbar run button should work to run the same entry point again.

I guess there are other ways to make this run button work but as I said, I almost never use this one myself.
Context menu `Run in Dartium`, `Run as Javascript` for web applications and context menu `Run` for command line scripts worked always for me.

Comment: I feel dumb, and yet, the actions I took seemed to be the most obvious intuitive path for new users. I think the Dart Editor team should consider this, perhaps selecting a file and clicking the green run button should get it to run that file when "Always Run Last Launch" is off. Or something. Anything but the current behavior. :D Thank you again so much! This problem deterred me for a whole year!

Comment: I'm not able to understand your suggestion. There can be many runable files in a single Dart package (in web, bin, example, test, tool, ...).
It hurt me when I read your question that you dropped/postponed Dart because of this and I thought a while about how to solve it so it doesn't happen again. The message you got is quite clear IMHO. I suppose the main problem are expectations and assumptions users make because of their previous experience. I guess DartEditor needs an additional functionality at startup which disables/deletes all outdated knowledge the user has acquired previously ;-)

Comment: That would help, yes. ;) But consider these actions and tell me whether it seems obvious. I'm a new user. I open DartEditor. I choose to open Sunflower demo. I click the green Run button and get that error: "...please select a runnable resource". Yes, the error is kind of clear. So I click sunflower.html to highlight it in the interface in order to "select" it. I click Run again. Same error message. Not intuitive. I guess DartEditor needs developers to delete all knowledge and assumptions about what should make sense to new users because they are used to doing it a certain way for so long. ;-)

Comment: In fact, what I described is exactly what Visual Studio C# .NET does and it is the only thing Microsoft has ever done that makes any kind of sense. When you click to select a file in the left navigation and then click the Run button at the top, that is the file that is selected to run. Since Dart looks like it would appeal to a lot of C# developers (C# is even listed in Wikipedia as a language that influenced Dart), this set of users will be very accustomed to the arguably logical action path I described in my previous comment. I think it's important that Dart Editor addresses this.

Comment: This seems to work in DartEditor too. I just tried it. I select a file and click the `run` button in the toolbar and the file is launched. When no file is selected (I selected a directory) I get an error message (but a different one than you got - I use a development release). What behavior do you expect from DartEditor when no or no runable file is selected?

Comment: I can no longer confirm this, but I think this problem only happens the first time Dart Editor is used before running something. I tried many numerous things last night and last year, including selecting files and clicking the green button. I kept getting that message in response. But now, having successfully run a file, the green Run button gets me to the next step no matter what I do (with and without "Always Run Last Launch" checked, etc)--absolutely not the case before! Quite a gotcha for new users and something easy for developers to miss. Again, I can no longer confirm original behavior.

Comment: Thanks for this feedback and confirmation. I'll create a bug report.

Comment: Yes, version 1.5.3. Thank you for this!